# Ordering results from Collections.frequency

Tags: java, filtering, hashset

I have got an ArrayList with 500+ words in. I'm trying to organise them into a list where the word that appears the most is at the top and then the 2nd most frequent and so on.

So far I've managed to filter out words with a frequency of less than 5 with the code below however I cannot work out how I can organise these results into a list of their frequencies in descending order.

```
    Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(wordsL);

    for (String key : unique) {
      if (Collections.frequency(wordsL, key) > 5) {
//        println(Collections.frequency(wordsL, key));
        lwords.add(key);
        println(lwords);
      }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: part of another process... irrelevant.

Comment: wordsL is arrayList of type string

Comment: Why not using `Map<String, Integer>` for counting. This can be [sorted by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java) later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map<String, Integer>` for counting.

You can later [sort the map by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java).

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm new to this and I am unfamiliar with maps, great help!